# How do you merge two faces that are connected by two differently sized edges?

Tags: modeling, faces

I am trying to merge/dissolve these two faces, but so far any option just removes the central vertex and dissolves it into an "average" face. How do I just merge them as if I removed the intersecting edge only?

Reference: [image]

Comment: You could key X and delete both faces. Then X delete the two edges that you want to join. Last, switch to vertex select mode, shift select the 6, 7, or 8 remaining vertices, and key F to make an n-gon face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Just select that single Edge
  [image: Beginning selection of single Edge]
- Delete it with <kbd>X</kbd>, this will leave a hole in your mesh
  [image: left hole in mesh]
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-Select all surrounding edges
  [image: Selected Edges]
- and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill in a new Face
  [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Edit mode> Face selection>  <kbd>RMB</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  the desired faces>  <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Rough end result:

[image]

*If* the underlying structure is more complex than your orthographic view suggests, adding an inconspicuous loopcut or two may simplify things (so long as it won't be affected by doing so).

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: This should have worked but actually didn't change anything for me. It may be because one of my faces were created manually so I'm wondering if there is a double edge/vertex issue.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to get a single face out of that shape would make a large Ngon (a face with more than 4 vertices) Ngons create problems when subdividing and you are likely to run into non-planar geometry issues.

[image]

You'd get better topology by subdividing further and creating quads:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't looking for a seven -

Edit mode - Vertex selection >  <kbd>RMB</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

[image]

<kbd>F</kbd>  creates a face.

Then utilizing face selection (from other possible answer).

And  <kbd>F</kbd>  again.

End result may be:

[image]